# Unable to view tags

Tags: support, status-bydesign, tags

Whenever I click on a tag from a question, or try searching for a tag such as [movies] I get told I am on the featured tab and there are no questions.

[image]

This has only started happening in the last few days.

Is there a way to fix this behavior? Is it happening for anyone else?

Answer (score 1):

The list seems to work as expected. If there are no questions with a bounty, the "featured" tab is hidden.

This happens even on the normal bounty page, as well. To see this, you can go [here](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured) and see something similar to your error.

I think that the site remembers your favourite/last used tab. That tab, in your case, must have been the "featured" tab, which then disappeared once the bounties expired.

To replicate:

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nutrition?sort=featured

To "solve", just choose a different sort, e.g.:

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nutrition?sort=newest

Comment: I can "solve" it that way, but it seems to go to the featured tab by default for me, when I have not been on the featured tab in a long time. From the questions page, definitely not on the featured tab, I get the result above when searching for a tag.